# List of Functions in class - Dart/Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, class, dart

How to make list of functions **in class**?
I tried this:

```
class MyClass extends StatelessWidget{
 final List<Function> listOfFunctions = [
  _fun1,
  _fun2,
  _fun3,
 ];
}
```

but the list work only without class, in main() fuction

I know I can make in class empty list and use .new() or listOfFunctions[0] = _fun1; but it not enaugh for me

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you passing parameters into your function? It should still work.

Comment: @pskink thx it work, but only inside main(). U know why it doesn't work in class?

Comment: Hi @Szymon, if you have an update to your question, please edit the question and not post an answer.

Comment: Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idk why, but when list is inside build Widget it work

```
class MyClass extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final List<Function> listOfFunctions = [
    _fun1,
    _fun2,
    _fun3,
   ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each function use () => {name}

Then call it using listOfFunctions [index] ()

This may be a workaround as I think it’s actually storing functions that call your function but I can’t figure out another way.

Comment: @Szymon                                                                                                         List<Function> listOfFunctions = [
    () => { fun1() },
    () => { fun2() },
    () => { fun3() }
  ];    Again, this is kind of a work around as it is calling functions that store your function but it still allows for return data and parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
String func1(){return "Function List1";}
String func2(String text){return text;}
//create list function
final List<Function> functions = [func1,func2,];
//use the list
//0 and 1 index of functions list 
print(functions[0]());
print(functions[1]("Function List2"));
```

result of code: Function List1
Function List2

Comment: My question was How to declare list of functions with empty elements, I'll declare later. I posted solution, but now I propose declare List in init() segment, u can override similar to build() segment